# Shouldn't I call next on future::stream::Unfold?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future

I'm calling `next` multiple times on a `Stream` returned by this function: https://github.com/sdroege/rtsp-server/blob/96dbaf00a7111c775348430a64d6a60f16d66445/src/listener/message_socket.rs#L43:

```
pub(crate) fn async_read<R: AsyncRead + Unpin + Send>(
    read: R,
    max_size: usize,
) -> impl Stream<Item = Result<Message<Body>, ReadError>> + Send {
    
    //...

    futures::stream::unfold(Some(state), move |mut state| async move {
        //...
    })
}
```

sometimes it works, but sometimes I get:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unfold must not be polled after it returned `Poll::Ready(None)`', /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-util-0.3.13/src/stream/unfold.rs:115:21
```

The error comes from https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.2/src/futures_util/stream/unfold.rs.html#112

but I couldn't understand why. Shouldn't I be free to call `next` on a Stream, in a loop?

Comment: *"Shouldn't I be free to call next on a Stream, in a loop?"* - sure, but you should stop after it returns `None`. Have a look at the `Stream` [documentation](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#tymethod.poll_next): *"`Poll::Ready(None)` means that the stream has terminated, and `poll_next` should not be invoked again"*. It is very similar to `Iterator`s in this regard.

Comment: Its hard to answer your question directly since you're lacking a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You don't even include the part where you're calling `next()`. Its impossible to say what exactly you're doing wrong or what should be done to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is an error for a reason, as it likely means that you are doing something wrong: when a stream returns `Poll::Ready(None)`, it means that the stream is completed (in a similar fashion to `Iterator`, as has been commented).

However, if you are still sure that this is what you want to do, then you can call [`stream.fuse()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/prelude/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.fuse) in order to silence the error and simply return `Poll::Ready(None)` forever.